# WPF Dialog Result

Tags: wpf, vb.net

Hello everyone I'm getting some strange error, if any of you could help me out?
Error is :
Error   1   'OK' is not a member of 'Boolean?'.

Code:

```
  If GetVer > CurrentVersion Then
        GetUpd = MsgBox(ProgramName & " is an old version." & vbCrLf & "New Update is available" & _
        vbCrLf & "Current version: " & CurrentVersion & vbCrLf & "Version Available: " & _
        GetVer & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Update Now?", vbYesNo, "Update")

        If GetUpd = vbYes Then
            Dim sfd As New SaveFileDialog

            sfd.FileName = IO.Path.GetFileName(GetVerLink)
            If sfd.ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK Then
                My.Computer.Network.DownloadFile(GetVerLink, sfd.FileName)
            End If
        End If
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In WPF, [ShowDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.showdialog.aspx) returns a  `Nullable(Of Boolean)`, not an enum.  You need to check via:

```
If sfd.ShowDialog = True Then
```

Comment: I need to make it if user click YES since there is yes and no?

Comment: @Onlykl In WPF, "True" is the yes case, "False" is the no case (and "Nothing" would be the canceled/closed case.  This does what you want.